# Hudson - Run console app and fail build if exit code is anything other than 0

Tags: c#, .net, build, continuous-integration, hudson

I want to run a console app utility as a Windows Batch Command step in my Hudson build. If the console application returns anything other than an exit code of 0, I want to fail my Hudson build. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behaviour, so it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't want to waste a lot of time writing a utility if my approach wouldn't work.

Comment: As a followup, doing `Environment.Exit(1)` from my C# console application will cause Hudson to fail the build.